# jquery creating or inserting html objects/elements

Tags: jquery

i'm all new to all this so i have this problem. i have to make a box in my blog and i didn't get any clue how to do it by only using jquery. on this site www.trojka.rs on right side you'll see box with header "sociometar". i need to make something like that.. so i only need guidance how to do it or where could i find anything that could help me.
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following tutorials:

[Basic Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

[HTML DOM Elements using Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp)

They explain from basics and are pretty good. You will have to do some reading.

Comment: yea, know that site.i found the way to create that list i need.

Comment: var mojalista= jQuery('<ul/>');
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
mojalista.append(jQuery('<li/>').text(i));
}
jQuery(".content-sidebar").append(mojalista);